# Unable to update-container on gcloud's containerised-vm

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I've created a containerised vm on gcloud, I specified some container image while creating the vm. 

 Now the container runs fine but when I try to update the image on the vm, I get the error -  `policyEvaluationPassed: false`

```
actualMeasurements:[...
3: {
     hashAlgo: "SHA1"      
     pcrNum: "PCR_8"      
     value: "OQ7Xv+6d2IRFohMlDWqy2QQoQqo="      
    }
]
policyMeasurements:[...
3: {
     hashAlgo: "SHA1"      
     pcrNum: "PCR_8"      
     value: "OQ7Xv+6d2IRFohMlDWqy2QQoQqo="      
    }
]
```

The sha value of pcr differs, I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

I had to run `gcloud compute instances update my-instance-name --shielded-learn-integrity-policy` to update the vm's integration policy.